# Using JSONPath to check for Boolean values

Tags: jsonpath

I'm trying to write a JSONPath expression to check if `active=true` for this simple object.

```
{
    "active": true
}
```

Is this possible in JSONPath?  I can't seem to get it to work in any online JSONPath evaluator.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work

```
final Configuration conf = Configuration.defaultConfiguration();
try    {
    Object returnObj = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(responseBody).read("$.active");
System.out.println(returnObj);
}
catch (PathNotFoundException e){
    System.err.println("JsonPath not found : " + path);
}
```